# bootstrap mobile page background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background-color

The following page has black background when i view it on my mobile device. The background color is white on a web browser. How can I make both mobile and web background same?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the background-color to the body element in CSS.

```
body {
background-color: white !important;
}
```

[CSS Background Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)